# How do I change a form value in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

We are using Django 1.4.3 with django-cities-light 2.1.5 to create our website. We are using the form's `__init__` method to update the lists of regions and cities. The problem is that if the user selected a city and the form doesn't validate, I want to change the region selection to the region of the selected city. Here is the code:

```
def __init__(self, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ContentItemModelForm, self).__init__(*args, instance=instance, **kwargs)
    ....
    ....
    ....
    country_id = None
    if ((hasattr(self, "initial")) and ("country_id" in self.initial)):
        country_id = int(self.initial['country_id']) if self.initial['country_id'] else None
    elif ((hasattr(self, "data")) and (u'country_id' in self.data)):
        country_id = int(self.data[u'country_id']) if self.data[u'country_id'] else None
    region_id = None
    if ((hasattr(self, "initial")) and ("region_id" in self.initial)):
        region_id = int(self.initial['region_id']) if self.initial['region_id'] else None
    elif ((hasattr(self, "data")) and (u'region_id' in self.data)):
        region_id = int(self.data[u'region_id']) if self.data[u'region_id'] else None
    city_id = None
    if ((hasattr(self, "initial")) and ("city_id" in self.initial)):
        city_id = int(self.initial['city_id']) if self.initial['city_id'] else None
    elif ((hasattr(self, "data")) and (u'city_id' in self.data)):
        city_id = int(self.data[u'city_id']) if self.data[u'city_id'] else None
    if (city_id):
        city_obj = City.objects.get(geoname_id=city_id)
        country_id = city_obj.country_id
        region_id = city_obj.region_id
        # Set current values of country_id and region_id - commented (not working).
        #self.fields['country_id'].initial = country_id
        #self.fields['region_id'].initial = region_id
    self.fields['region_id'].choices = [("", "(None)", ),]+[(obj.id, obj.name) for obj in Region.objects.filter(country_id=country_id).order_by("name")]
    if (region_id):
        self.fields['city_id'].choices = [("", "(None)", ),]+[(obj.geoname_id, obj.name) for obj in City.objects.filter(country_id=country_id, region_id=region_id).order_by("name")]
    else:
        self.fields['city_id'].choices = [("", "(None)", ),]+[(obj.geoname_id, obj.name) for obj in City.objects.filter(country_id=country_id).order_by("name")]
```

The code that checks the current values of city_id, region_id and country_id is too long and I didn't find a way to shorten it. And the commented lines (`self.fields['country_id'].initial = country_id` and `self.fields['region_id'].initial = region_id`) don't work if they are not commented - if only country and city are selected then the selected region is "(None)" (if the form does not validate). If the form validates then we assign the country_id and region_id values according to the selected city (the country and region are not saved to the database).

Here is the city validation:

```
def clean_city_id(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    country_id = cleaned_data['country_id'] if (cleaned_data.has_key('country_id')) else None
    region_id = cleaned_data['region_id'] if (cleaned_data.has_key('region_id')) else None
    city_id = cleaned_data['city_id'] if (cleaned_data.has_key('city_id')) else None
    if (not(city_id)):
        if (region_id):
            error_message = "If you select a country and a state/region, you must select a city."
            self._errors["city_id"] = self.error_class([error_message])
            raise forms.ValidationError(error_message)
        elif (country_id):
            error_message = "If you select a country, you must select a city."
            self._errors["city_id"] = self.error_class([error_message])
            raise forms.ValidationError(error_message)
    return city_id
```

Do you know how do we assign the correct values to the country and region?

(Edit): We want to have `selected="selected"` in the HTML in the correct region after a city is selected, and not in the first "(None)" region (also if the user didn't select a region). We use AJAX to update the lists after the user selects a new country or region, but we don't want to use AJAX immediately after loading the form.

Thanks,
Uri.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest alternative way to solve the problem. Alternative to "manually" setting values for user - let user do it itself. Like this:

1) Trigger form GET on select change event

2) in those event callbacks pass form data to view - just like you do with POST. Just do GET request not POST request.

3) In view just pass request.GET as first parameter to form instead of request.POST

4) Let your existing logic do the magic in form init method.

5) Return form template with correct and valid choices from view

6) switch existing form with new form.

Thats how i would do it anyway. No need to assign anything. Let user do the choices they can after refreshing the form.

Comment: The form method is post and we don't want to change it. We use AJAX to update the cities and/or regions lists if the user selects a new country or region. But when the form loads after the user submits if the form doesn't validate then we don't want to use AJAX, we want the form to load with the correct country and region (if the user selected a city). The country is always correct but the region can be "(None)" if the user didn't change it before selecting a city.

Comment: As i see - these kinds of forms always have country selection before region and/or city selection. User should not even be able to change the value of city to something that is not allowed by previous country choice. But it is up to you - changing the things "magically" yourself instead of resetting the value and letting user to do it, always feels strange to user. In any case. I offered easyest solution which i could think of. If you do not "want" to use it, then you'll have to "want" to work on harder one. Good luck.

Comment: The user can select a country, leave the region as None and select a city. In this case he will see all the cities in the selected country. After posting the form we want to change the region to the region of the selected city, also if the form doesn't validate.

Comment: If you just want to set region to city's region, then do it in form save method or something and you will not have to present the results to user any more. That't. If you feel you need to present the changes to user, then do it like i suggested. Along with (error) message that hints that user needs to set region too.